# Import custom defined functions

Tags: python

**Set-up**

I have 2 `.py` files in 2 different locations, i.e. `'mypath/folder_A'` and `'mypath/folder_B'`.

File `A.py` contains 2 custom defined functions that need to be imported into `B.py`.

`A.py` looks like,

```
def test_function_1(x):
    y = x + 1
    return y

def test_function_2(x):
    y = x + 2
    return y
```

and `B.py` looks like,

```
os.chdir('/mypath/folder_A')
import A

test_function_1(1)
test_function_2(1)
```

---

**Issue**

When I run `B.py`, I get `NameError: name 'test_function_1' is not defined`.

But if I adjust `B.py` to,

```
from A import test_function_1, test_function_2
```

and run `B.py`, it works.

---

**Question**

How can I import the functions from `A.py` into `B.py` without having to name them all?

I.e. is there a `from A import everything`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what you are looking for:

```
from A import *
```

You can also do:

```
import A

A.test_function_1(1)
```

Or:

```
import A as a

a.test_function_1(1)
```

Also, libs are typically read from the `$PYTHONPATH`

So if you write this line in your `.bashrc`:

```
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/mypath/folder_A/"
```

To edit the `.bashrc` on GNU/Linux:

```
gedit $HOME/.bashrc
```

Then there is no need for your `os.chdir()`, you can directly import from anywhere.

Your `B.py` will look like:

```
from A import *

test_function_1(1)
test_function_2(1)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I haven't reached the level of bash scripts yet. Still running my scripts from the IDE. Will accept answer once I can.